# How to stop Modified By names from changing when moving files

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, versioning

I moved some files to another location on the same site sub-site to sub-site.

I used Content and Stucture as that retains the version and the locations are both buried a few deep on different sub-sites of the same site.

The versions were kept but the modified by names changed to me.  I had 28 versions of this document now when you check Verion History Modified By for all 28 is me.

How can I stop this from happening and can I get the correct names back?

I was thinking that I could just restore a previous version but when I go to View  another version all I get is a properites window?  I am only Site owner not admin.

Any help would be apprecitated.

Comment: check this one http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/06/move-files-between-document-libraries-with-metdata-version-history.html

Answer (score 2):

A powershell can be written to copy files with a system update to retain the modified by and modified columns, refer [link](http://sharepointhangout.com/simple-fix-splistitem-systemupdate-boolean-true-vs-false-explained/)

Second, check with your admin if they use any tool to move objects between environments (the one we have is Metalogix, we use for purposes like this).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Third party software is out of the question, as the time it would take to test the software and then allow us to use it per admin security standards is prohibitive.